# How to improve otsu threshold output

Tags: c++, opencv

I am using `otsu threshold` on an image.

 Here is the input image :

[image]

Here is the output :

[image]

Here is the code I am using:

```
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  title("Text Extractor");
  string win_name = "textextractor";
  Mat img_a;

  img_a = imread("../input/test_c.jpg");

  Mat img_a_gray;
  cvtColor(img_a, img_a_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);

  Mat img_a_blur;    
  GaussianBlur(img_a_gray, img_a_blur, Size(3, 3), 0, 0);

  Mat img_a_thres;
  // adaptiveThreshold(img_a_blur, img_a_thres, 255, ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, THRESH_BINARY, 5, 4);
  threshold(img_a_blur, img_a_thres, 0, 255, THRESH_OTSU);
  namedWindow(win_name + "_a", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
  imshow(win_name + "_a", img_a_thres);

  imwrite("../output/output_a.jpg", img_a_thres);

  waitKey(0);
  return 0;
}
```

The problem is that output has a black region on the bottom and on the left. What can I do to minimize/remove this ?

Edit:

I tried `equalizeHist()` and I am getting this:

[image]

Will try out breaking image into pieces and working them separately.

Sorry, my bad. The previous one is using adaptive filtering. Using `Otsu` I get this:

[image]

There is no change in otsu's output :/

Edit 2: Completed the Feng Tan algorithm, it gives better results but text looses clarity.

Code:

```
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/photo/photo.hpp"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  string win_name = "textextractor";

  Mat img_c;
  img_c = imread("../input/sample.jpg");

  Mat img_c_gray;
  cvtColor(img_c, img_c_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);

  Mat img_c_bin = Mat::zeros(img_c_gray.rows, img_c_gray.cols, CV_8UC1);

  int s_win = 17;
  int l_win = 35;

  double min_tau = 10;

  Rect roi_s = Rect(-s_win/2, -s_win/2, s_win, s_win);
  Rect roi_l = Rect(-l_win/2, -l_win/2, l_win, l_win);
  Rect img_c_roi = Rect(0, 0, img_c_gray.cols, img_c_gray.rows);

  for (size_t r = 0; r < img_c_gray.rows; r++) {
    for (size_t c = 0; c < img_c_gray.cols; c++) {
      double pthres = 255;

      Rect sROI = roi_s + Point(c, r);
      sROI = sROI & img_c_roi;
      if(sROI.width == 0 || sROI.height == 0) {
        continue;
      }

      Rect lROI = roi_l + Point(c, r);
      lROI = lROI & img_c_roi;
      if(lROI.width == 0 || lROI.height == 0) {
        continue;
      }

      Mat sROI_gray = img_c_gray(sROI);
      Mat lROI_gray = img_c_gray(lROI);

      double s_stdDev = 0;
      double l_stdDev = 0;
      double s_mean = 0;
      double l_mean = 0;
      double l_min = DBL_MAX;

      for (size_t r = 0; r < sROI_gray.rows; r++) {
        for (size_t c = 0; c < sROI_gray.cols; c++) {
          s_mean += sROI_gray.at<unsigned char>(r, c);
        }
      }

      s_mean = s_mean / static_cast<double> (sROI_gray.cols * sROI_gray.rows);

      for (size_t r = 0; r < sROI_gray.rows; r++) {
        for (size_t c = 0; c < sROI_gray.cols; c++) {
          double diff = sROI_gray.at<unsigned char> (r, c) - s_mean;
          s_stdDev += diff * diff;
        }
      }

      s_stdDev = sqrt(s_stdDev / static_cast<int> (sROI_gray.cols * sROI_gray.rows));

      for (size_t r = 0; r < lROI_gray.rows; r++) {
        for (size_t c = 0; c < lROI_gray.cols; c++) {
          l_mean += lROI_gray.at<unsigned char> (c, r);

          if(lROI_gray.at<unsigned char> (r, c) < l_min) {
            l_min = lROI_gray.at<unsigned char> (r, c);
          }
        }
      }
      l_mean = l_mean / static_cast<double> (lROI_gray.cols * lROI_gray.rows);

      for (size_t r = 0; r < lROI_gray.rows; r++) {
        for (size_t c = 0; c < lROI_gray.cols; c++) {
          double diff = lROI_gray.at<unsigned char> (r, c) - l_mean;
          l_stdDev += diff * diff;
        }
      }
      l_stdDev = sqrt(l_stdDev / static_cast<double> (lROI_gray.cols * lROI_gray.rows));

      double tau = ((s_mean - l_min) * (1 - s_stdDev / l_stdDev)) / 2.0;
      if(tau < min_tau) {
        tau = min_tau;
      }

      double threshold = s_mean - tau;

      unsigned char pixel_val = img_c_gray.at<unsigned char>(r, c);
      if(pixel_val >= threshold) {
        img_c_bin.at<unsigned char> (r, c) = 255;
      } else {
        img_c_bin.at<unsigned char> (r, c) = 0;
      }
    }
  }

  namedWindow(win_name + "_c", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
  imshow(win_name + "_c", img_c_bin);

  imwrite("../output/output_c.jpg", img_c_bin);
  waitKey(0);
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Try adaptive thresholding: http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html

Comment: I was asked to try and make otsu's output as good as it can be. I have tried it as you might have seen in comment. Its better, but I still need to use otsu :/

Comment: Try `cv2.eqHist()`, before passing the image for otsu.

Comment: I think in this case splitting up the image to equal sized individual clusters of pixels could yield a better result, calling otsu on each separately.

Comment: Try blurring the image using `cv2.medianBlur()` before trying out the above mentioned steps

Comment: I am doing a gaussian blur already. I found gaussian blur to be a better performer than median blur

Comment: How good do the results need to be ? With adaptive thresholding, I get results a bit better with a little post-processing : despeckling, closing and then selecting only components with a certain size (here, 40 pixels)

Comment: If I can get the `adaptive algo` equivalent results using `otsu`, that will be awesome.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I was able to obtain after some trial and run. Initially I ***median blurred*** the original image. Then I applied **adpative threshold** to the blurred image.

This is what I got:

***1. Adaptive Threshold using Gaussian filter:***

[image]

***2. Adaptive Threshold using Mean filter:***

[image]

From here on you can carry out a series of morphological operations that best suits your final image. :)

Comment: These are pretty good results :) I tried denoising but that didn't really affect the image much. But I have also replicated the results that you have now. `Otsu` is still not working out. I am trying to check out the algo and tweak stuff. This is fun :)

Comment: Have a look at [THIS ADVANCED THRESHOLDING](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/120338/is-there-sauvolas-or-niblacks-threshold-binarization-algorithms) techniques as well. You have to code them yourself though :)

Answer (score 0):

You should try using [*CLAHE*](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d5/daf/tutorial_py_histogram_equalization.html).

I tried it on *MATLAB* using:

```
Ia = imread('FHXTJ.jpg');
I = rgb2gray(Ia);
A = adapthisteq(I, 'clipLimit', 0.02, 'Distribution', 'rayleigh');
```

Result: [image: CLAHE Result]

Note: You can apply thresholding on this image. Otsu should work fine now.

[image: Threshold [65, 152]]